# Concern about publishing with SiteEdit on two different websites

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We have two websites one for mobile and one to be accessed from PC. Our Blueprint is setup so that content is shared between both websites. The PC website has SiteEdit enabled on it. My concern is, when a person uses SiteEdit on the PC website, then will the page for the mobile website be published automatically or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The content will not automatically be published to the mobile web site unless you explicitly configure this.

However, the shared content will be modified, of course, and as soon as someone decides to publish, the mobile site will be updated with content that is optimized for your PC site. For example: your PC site may have more room for text, so you might be tempted to create headers etc. that are too big for your mobile site.

The fundamental question is whether you can share content between two different media. Will the benefits of a simpler blueprint outweigh the possible conflicts? You will have to decide this for yourself.

Comment: also SiteEdit is only publishing to the Staging target (its own website basically), it will never automatically publish to the Live target, that is an action you will have to start manually, and if it is something you are concerned about, you can always restrict the users who are able to publish to the Live target (so you have room for a proper review process).